# Help with intro to number theory question

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $m$ and $n$ be integers with $m > 0$ and $n > 0$. If $(n,m)\mid(a−b)$, then the system

$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv a\pmod m \\ 
x\equiv b\pmod m 
\end{cases}
$$

has a solution. Describe how to find a solution.

Can anyone explain how to solve this for me? I have been looking at it, but I do not know where to begin or what to look for when solving it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider using Mathjax for mathematics :)

Comment: What is Mathjax?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: I have touched base on it, I wouldn't say that I fully grasp it though.

Comment: Is the question how to _prove_ that it has a solution?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of $x\equiv a\pmod n$ are $x=a+kn$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$. Similarly, that of $x\equiv b\pmod m$ are $x=b+lm$ with $l\in\Bbb Z$.

By *Bezout's identity*, we have $u_0,v_0\in\Bbb Z$ such that $(n,m)=u_0n+v_0m$. By the hipothesis, this implies that 
$$b-a=un+vm$$
for $u=\frac{b-a}{(n,m)}\cdot u_0,\ v=\frac{b-a}{(n,m)}\cdot v_0$. But then consider
$$x:=a+un=b-vm\,.$$